# Extending a partial homeomorphism of $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: general-topology

Does every partial homoeomorphism of the rationals extend to an automorphism (a homeomorphism of the entire rationals)?

Specifically, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the rationals $\mathbb Q$, and $h:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism, then is there a homeomorphism $\hat h:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ such that $\hat h\restriction A=h$?

> Note that this would not necessarily happen in $\mathbb R$.
>
> For
>   instance, let $A=B=\{0,1,2\}$, $h(0)=0$, $h(1)=2$,  and $h(2)=1$.
>
> Then there can be no homeomorphism $\hat h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$
>   extending $h$.

Answer (score 3):

No. E.g. A = $\mathbb Q$ and B = $\mathbb Q^+$.
More generally, let A be any proper dense subset of $\mathbb Q$ and B homeomorphic but not dense. Any extension cannot reach outside the closure of B.

Comment: Nice simple example. I was about to give a complicated example but this does it all.  $Q$ is homeomorphic to  a proper subspace of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, indeed the set $A = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb N^*\}$ has the discrete topology, so it's homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^*$. On the other hand, the continuous map $f : A \to \Bbb N^*, x \mapsto 1/x$,  can't be extended to a continuous map $\tilde f : A \cup \{0\} \to \Bbb Q$, let alone to an homeomorphism $\tilde f : \Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$.